# Serialize/Deserialize an specific type array to xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization, exception

i got an issue on serialize/deserialize an Array of specific objects.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()] 
public class ctyp_HT
{
   private Operationalmessage[] opm;
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OpMessages", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   public Operationalmessage[] P_OpMessages{
      get {
          return this.opm;
      }
      set {
          this.opm= value;
      }
   }
}
```

With set{} in this property the serialize process crash on runtime. Without set{} it will work, but why. The class is marked as [System.SerializableAttribute()].
Here is the functioncall i use in combination with a generic function:

```
SerializeObject<ctyp_HT>(objInstance);

public static string SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject)
    {
        if (serializableObject == null) { return string.Empty; }

        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                stream.Position = 0;
                xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }
            return xmlDocument.InnerXml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\n\n\n" + ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

What im doing wrong? Thx for help.

Edit after first comment:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class Operationalmessage : I_Information
{
   private object objGen;
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OPEN", typeof(ctyp_intEndlage_AUF), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CLOSE", typeof(ctyp_intEndlage_ZU), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("BETWEEN", typeof(ctyp_intEndlage_ZWISCHEN), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("objIdentifier")]
   public object P_objGen
  {
     get { return objGen; }
     set { objGen = value; }
  }
  private UnnamedChoice0 objIdentifier;
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
  public UnnamedChoice0 P_objIdentifier
  {
     get { return objIdentifier; }
     set { objIdentifier = value; }
  }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
  public string P_Info
  {
     get
     {
        if(objGen is I_Information) return objIdentifier + "(" + ((I_Information)objGen).P_Info + ")"; 
        else return objIdentifier + "(" + objGen + ")";
     }
  }
}
```

the unnamedchoice is an public enum. the class ctyp_intEndlage_Auf/ZU/Zwischen all the same with different names, because of my generator.

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class ctyp_intEndlage_AUF : I_Information
{
   private ctyp_Infoquelle_BOOL1_In Informationsquelle = null;
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Informationsquelle", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   public ctyp_Infoquelle_BOOL1_In P_Informationsquelle
   {
      get { return Informationsquelle; }
      set { Informationsquelle = value; }
   }
   private string Extension = "036";
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Extension", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   public string P_Extension
   {
      get { return Extension; }
      set { Extension = value; }
   }
   public string P_Info
   {
      get 
      {
         string result = "";         return "( " + Informationsquelle.P_Info + " "  + Extension + " "  + result + ")"; 
      }
   }
   public ctyp_intEndlage_AUF() 
   {
      Informationsquelle = new ctyp_Infoquelle_BOOL1_In();
   }
}
```

and the last class bool1

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class ctyp_Infoquelle_BOOL1_In : I_Information
{
   private object objGen;
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("HardwareEingang", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("KoppelEingang", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("objIdentifier")]
   public object P_objGen
   {
      get { return objGen; }
      set { objGen = value; }
   }
   private UnnamedChoice1 objIdentifier;
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
   public UnnamedChoice1 P_objIdentifier
   {
      get { return objIdentifier; }
      set { objIdentifier = value; }
   }
   public string P_Info
   {
      get
      {
         if(objGen is I_Information) return objIdentifier + "(" + ((I_Information)objGen).P_Info + ")"; 
         else return objIdentifier + "(" + objGen + ")";
      }
   }
   public ctyp_Infoquelle_BOOL1_In() 
   {
   }
}
```

The Property P_Info is declared in I_Information interface.
Sry for all the german names =).

Comment: Could you include `Operationalmessage`? Hard to tell what's wrong without the code. Btw: For Arrays you want to use the `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes instead of `XmlElement` (Except if you don't want the collection wrapped with an Element).

Comment: When you serialize the properties must be public not private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created .net fiddle with proper code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/67evia

Your problem was using private fields in `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute` class.

You have:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("objIdentifier")]
```

And it has to be:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("P_objIdentifier")]
```

I have also extended error logging in your serilizer method to properly read all exceptions.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var log = (ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace );
    var extemp = ex.InnerException;
    while (extemp != null)
    {
        log += "\n\n\n" + extemp.Message + "\n" + extemp.StackTrace;
        extemp = extemp.InnerException;
    }
    return log;
}
```

Comment: Wow big thanks for your great investigating in my problem. I think i was blind, but the error messages wasn't helping me out. Problem solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: addendum: this kind of extended exception logging is the tool i needed.